# Harmonic solutions

Tags: calculus-of-variations, harmonic-functions

Assume that $\Omega\subset R^2$ is an open bounded set with a smooth boundary, $g:\partial\Omega\to R$ is a continuous map and $\{b_i \ | \ i=1,2,\ldots,d\}$ is a finite subset of $\Omega$.

$$\left\{\begin{align*}& \Delta \Phi = 2\pi \sum_{i=1}^d \delta_{b_i} &&\textrm{in} \ \ \Omega \\ &\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial\nu} = g &&\textrm{on} \ \  \partial\Omega\end{align*}\right.$$

I would like to ask, if maybe someone of you know how to prove the existence of solutions of the above problem. I tried with Green function but I don't know how to use it to obtain the specific Neumann boundary conditions.

Comment: What boundary condition does your Green's function satisfy? The usual trick with a linear problem is to find a solution to the inhomogeneous equation with a homogeneous boundary condition, and a solution to the homogeneous equation with an inhomogeneous boundary condition, and then add them. So it is enough to solve the Laplace equation with your boundary condition and the Green's function with the homogeneous boundary condition.

Answer (score 0):

You need an additional condition for there to be solutions.  Think of this in terms of heat flow.
You're asking for a steady-state temperature distribution in $\Omega$ with given heat sources and given heat flows across the boundary.  The rate of change of the
total amount of heat in the region is then the sum of the sources plus the flux across the boundary.  If that is not $0$, there can't be a steady state.